# The problem with the density of smoke in the simulation

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I have a scene with fire and smoke simulation.

I have changed the parameters of gravity to make fire and smoke tending down to the ground (it will be a fiery trail of soaring object).

Below there is a plane-obstacle for the fire and smoke, so the smoke should be spread over the surface.

However, for some reason, somewhere in the middle of the simulation, instead of a thick cloud of smoke, I see a very small amount of smoke along the surface, which spreads not evenly over it.

[image]

What could be the reason, and how can I fix it? Screenshots with the settings are below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
P.S. The lighting in the scene is not very good, that's why the smoke looks black, and the topology of the fire emitter is not the best, but I think this is not the reason...

P.S.P.S. I tried to increase the dissolve time, but after the first big bunch of smoke, smoke density decreases again. Also, I do not understand why the smoke spreads over the surface so uneven:
[image]

Blend file: [image]

Comment: No blend file for us to play with?

Comment: @cegaton Yes, I attached it to the post, thank you!